# Update install profile- with or without drush

Tags: drush, updating, installation-profiles

I'm fairly new to drupal and I'm getting used to drush. I'm trying to update my site with `drush up` and it seems to update **core**, **contrib modules** and the **database** okay. However, I have several modules that came with my install `profile` that don't appear to be updating.

Do I have to update the install profile manually (upload the files myself) or is there some other way to update an install profile?

Thank you!

Comment: Which installation profile you are using?

Comment: I'm using the Panopoly profile/distribution but I assume the process to update one profile is the same or similar to others. Is there good documentation about this somewhere?

Comment: I found a similar thread, but please feel free to add to this discussion.

http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/47663/how-do-i-update-a-drupal-distribution-to-a-newer-version